# Date picker issue on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, css, javaquery

How can I assign the currently selected date instead of `new date()` in the following code?

So from here each time when I refresh, it will give me currently selected date in textbox instead of becoming blank

```
$(".date-pick").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ..

use onclose event of datepicker to set the value of date .... "$(this).val()" this will have the value of currently selected date and set this value to Html Element using  "document.getElementsByClassName('.date-pick').value"

```
$( ".date-pick" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('.date-pick').value= $(this).val(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I've edited your answer to improve readability, but you should include some semblance of an explanation